# HttpClient's WebRequestHandler hanging with partial response

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to use [WebRequestHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler.aspx) with HttpClient in an ASP.NET MVC controller with .NET 4.0. I've got the latest HttpClient installed from NuGet.

When passing a WebRequestHandler to HttpClient, requests never complete. Looking via a debugging proxy, responses from the server just get cut off at some point through the response body. Doesn't seem to be a pattern as to where it cuts off.

Here's a test case:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        var google = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com");
        return View(google);
    }
}
```

It works fine if I replace WebRequestHandler with HttpClientHandler, but I need to add a client certificate.

I've tried changing various settings of WebRequestHandler, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this just seems to be a bug and regression in HttpClient.

I went back to v2.0.20710.0 and it works fine.

Comment: This works for me using the latest HttpClient.  Are you sure you aren't leaking the task returned by GetStringAsync?

Comment: Pretty positive I'm not... did you try with .NET 4.0?

Comment: Yep, tried it on 4.0 and 4.5 in a console app using your sample without the await (just getting .Result).  I also tried it in 4.0 with the await, using the Microsoft.BCL async package.  If you have an isolated repro can you share it?

Comment: Just tried it in a console app and it worked fine. Seems to be a problem with ASP.NET. Have updated the code above to show the complete controller.

Comment: I see you are still using await in the sample.  I take it you are developing in VS 2012 using the Microsoft.BCL.Async package?  In that case are you running on a the same machine with NetFx 4.5 or a different machine with NetFX 4.0?

Comment: Also, which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Yep, using VS 2012 with BCL.Async. On the same machine that has 4.5 installed. MVC 4.